# OFFSET Unique Name Manager

Tags: excel, vba, offset

| Company | Client Name |
| --- | --- |
| Alpha | James |
| Alpha | Andrew |
| Bravo | Phyl |
| Charles | Bryan |

Total number of rows given = 4 in cell (TotalRows)

If I would like to create a name manager that provides dynamic search for Company, it will be
=OFFSET(ClientDB!$A$2,0,0,TotalRows,1)

However, how do I provide distinct unique results for Company (E.g. Only Alpha, Bravo,Charles and not Alpha, Alpha, Bravo, Charles)? I tried =UNIQUE(OFFSET(ClientDB!$A$2,0,0,TotalRows,1)) but failed to work.

Also for Name Manager for Client Name how do I provide the same dynamic formula such that when Company Name is selected, it will show the corresponding Client Name? I will require this Name Manager as the rowSource for the VBA userform.

Thank you!

Comment: Re your `UNIQUE` formula, what do you mean by "failed to work"? Does your version of Excel not have that function?

Comment: It doesnt work within the name manager "Refers to:" as the output is blank I believe unique does not work within the name manager

Comment: That does not mean that it is not working. UNIQUE works perfectly fine within a Defined Name.

Comment: Perhaps you haven't clarified your post clearly enough. Perhaps you were hoping to use this as the source for a Data Validation list? If so, that's something you need to make explicit in your post.

Comment: `OFFSET` can return a reference to an actual worksheet range; `UNIQUE` can only return an array, which however can be made to spill into an actual worksheet range. That's an important distinction.